# Using JMeter to test Eclipse RCP applications

Tags: eclipse, performance, jmeter, automated-tests, eclipse-rcp

I have a question about using JMeter to launch performance tests on an Eclipse RCP application. I've been able to feed JUnit .jar Files to JMeter and launch them. However, they are just simple jar files. When I tried to put an Eclipse application and some tests in JMeter's lib/junit folder (jar files are stored in features and plugins folder of eclipse), JMeter seems not to be able to resolve these jars and no test is shown. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter is meant to capture and replay sequences of HTTP requests. RCP is a framework to build desktop applications which usually don't communicate over HTTP. Therefore JMeter is most likely the wrong tool.

In order to create UI tests for RCP applications, you may want to look into tools like SWTBot or RCPTT.

For performance tests, you are likely better off exposing the code to be tested so that it can be accessed headless - i.e. without requiring UI interactions. If you are using Jobs or similar means to do expensive computations in the background, pure UI interactions aren't usually a performance critical part.

I found a hint that RCPTT can be used to verify performance criteria so some extent here: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/rcp-testing-tool-rcptt-basic-tutorial/

Similarly, you could use SWTBot to measure and record the execution time for certain scenarios.

Comment: Well tools like SWTBot or RCPTT are suitable for UI tests but the support for performance tests are quite limited (e.g. in RCPTT we can set a time limit for a test but we cannot export test results and compare results between test launches)

Comment: Right, please see my edited answer. Reify your post if that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Well I accept your answer since it takles the original question about JMeter. I guess I'll ask another question about performance testing with RCP applications. Thanks.